# Unit Test Mocking WSFederationAuthenticaitonModule

Tags: c#, mocking, wif

Our team currently uses WIF for authentication. Throughout our code we use

```
SessionManager.GetClaim(CustomClaimTypes.Username)
```

and other SessionManager functions to identify the currently logged in user when manipulate data. I recently started writing unit tests for one of our projects, which obviously fails because SessionManager is null.

I ran into the same issue when a test method called a function that retrieves data from the Session. To resolve this I included the Moq library and mocked the Session as follows:

```
var mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
mockHttpContext.SetupGet(c => c.Session).Returns(mockSession.Object);
mockHttpContext.SetupSet(c => c.Session["test"] = "test");
```

This is working as expected, but I can't find a way to mock FederatedAuthentication's WSFederationauthenticationModule. Here's where the code fails:

```
SessionSecurityToken stoken = new SessionSecurityToken(prin);
FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken(stoken, true); // WSFederationAuthenticationModule throws a null reference
```

I tried creating a WSFederationauthenticationModule and initilizing it, but that didn't work:

```
WSFederationAuthenticationModule ws = new WSFederationAuthenticationModule();
ws.Init(mockHttpContext.ApplicationInstance);
```

I can't seem to find any useful resources to help me out with this. Any help out there?